# Find index of visible items and select url to open in new window

Tags: javascript, jquery

I cant figure out how to highlight just the visible items/rows in a table, and skip hidden ones.

Then when one is highlighted (with up/down keys), how do I select the URL and open it in a new window on "enter"-keypress.

https://jsfiddle.net/jasq6zkn/

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#search").on("keyup", function(e) {
        if(e.which != 13||e.which != 38||e.which != 40){
        var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        $("#data tr").filter(function() {
            $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
        });
        }
    });
});

function highlight(tableIndex) {
    if( (tableIndex+1) > $('#data tr').length )
        tableIndex = 0;

   console.log(tableIndex);

    if($('#data tr:eq('+tableIndex+')').length > 0)
    {
        // Remove other highlights
        $('#data tr').removeClass('highlight');
        // Highlight your target
        $('#data tr:eq('+tableIndex+')').addClass('highlight');
    }
}
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    switch(e.which)
    {
        case 13:
            alert('Opening url');
            $('#search').val("");
            $('#data tr').removeClass('highlight');
            //OPEN THE URL HERE
            break;
        case 38:
            highlight($('#data tr.highlight').index() - 1);
            break;
        case 40:
            highlight($('#data tr.highlight').index() + 1);
            break;
    }
});
```

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try something like this:

```
 switch(e.which)
 {
    case 13:
        $('#search').val("");
        var url = $('#data tr.highlight>td').eq(2).text(); // Extract the "url" value from the third cell (index #2) of current raw (this is actually an email..)
        $('#data tr').removeClass('highlight'); // Remove hightlight
        window.open(url, '_blank'); // Navigate to "url"
```

Comment: Nice, thanks! That solves the URL opening. (yea I know it is an email, but that's what the random generator gave me).

Just need the filtering and selection to skip the hidden rows now :-)

Comment: There is always a room for another new question ;)

Comment: Thought I had two :-) 
Anyways, second question would be:
I have added keyboard navigation of the rows, and enter to open the URL (as you suggested). However when you use the "search" field to limit the results the navigation is broken since some rows are hidden. Any ideas on how to solve that?
https://jsfiddle.net/79ydtrfm/